# Selenium WebDriver upload file C#

Tags: c#, selenium, file-upload, webdriver

I have a problem with upload file to Web system using selenium driver. So in my page I haven't any input to set file path and most of solutions which I founded in network not work for me. I have to click on upload file button and then set path to the file in window dialog. I found method which used from winforms SendKeys class:

```
SendKeys.SendWait(filePath);
SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
```

it works but only when the tests has full control of the machine (if not - the path have been sending somewhere not to dialog). And this is the problem because I'm not be able to get full control to machine where the test are running. Do you know a way how to upload file do not use SendKeys?

Comment: Use a shared drive instead. This is the easiest way to handle file upload. And, whatever way you want to upload the files you need to type filepath. Don't you?

Comment: how do you want to use a shared drive? I need to use files from hdd

Comment: [This](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/network-administration-granting-share-permissions.html) should show you how to. It doesn't matter if you configure the permission correctly

Comment: I think that I don't understand how to do this. Suppose that I will share files and click on upload button. Again I will have window to set path to file and then if machine haven't full control then path not have been set correctly. I don't have problem with share files on machine only with set path to the file.

Comment: You will do. They machine you are running the tests on has to have permission to access the shared drive and there are plenty of help how to set up shared drive.. you will send the filepath directly. something looks like `\\TestSharedFolderOnNetworkDrive\FilesToBeUploade.txt`

Comment: Ok I tried your way and the tests are still fail. I have machine where I ran the tests and not to block the desktop the tests are route to other machine. And I suppose that on other machine the path is not set because cursor is not set in dialog where the path can be set. Of course I shared uploaded file to that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I solved the problem. Below is example in Java how to do it but main point of that solution is create AutoIt script and then run exe file from C# code.

[Solution](http://www.testingexcellence.com/how-to-upload-files-using-selenium-and-autoit/)

Sample script should be changed because it works only on IE:

```
WinWaitActive("Choose file")
```

That line exclude other browsers. On Chrome for example the window named as "Open". After create and compile script enough to call:

```
Process.Start(filePath);
```