# C#: System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait does not work with the path as input

Tags: c#, string, upload, coded-ui-tests, sendkeys

Here is my code

```
private string path = Path.GetTempPath() + "Test.pdf";
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads;
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(path);
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.UIThreadOnly;
Keyboard.SendKeys("{Enter}");
```

There is a window explorer for opening a file. The file exists on the temp path. It sometimes works and sometimes it enter the path as `:\Users\....` which means it ignores `C`. I am not sure what is the problem? Why it is inconsistent? Any help is appreciated.

I already tried

```
private string path = @"" + Path.GetTempPath() + "Test.pdf";
```

but it is the same (sometimes works, sometimes does not)

I added empty char before the path

```
private string path = @" " + Path.GetTempPath() + "Test.pdf";
```

But still it is the same!

Comment: a solution is possible, create a console project, execute that project in a planned task of windos with the code SendKeys.SendWait (path), that project is separate or you would have two projects one with your open dialog and another with the project console Arley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Coded UI but it omitted a small number of characters randomly throughout the string. I never found out the real reason, but I got around the problem by sending the characters one at a time with a short pause between them. I use code similar to the following:

```
void SendKeysSlowly(string text)
{
    foreach ( char s in text )
    {
        SendKeys(s); // Choose the appropriate send routine
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50); // Milliseconds, adjust as needed
    }
}
```

Also, you should ensure the string always starts with a "C:"? You could add code of the form `Assert(path.StartsWith("C:\\"));` before the first `...Sendkeys` call.

Comment: I found another solution. I think the problem is the focus. We should make sure that the focus is on the textbox (filename). I did that using
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("%n");

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Test.pdf")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it does not work still omit the C.

Comment: This should probably help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18366/Sending-Keystrokes-to-another-Application-in-C

Comment: One more related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151598/selenium-webdriver-upload-file-c-sharp

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Mr. @harpun - if you run this code in any situation it would give you a proper path in string format in any / all situation. That is what was the question asked for. The context of usage is not clear (or out of my knowledge) so I suggested additional links / hints to see if the other part of code is written in right direction or not.